# how to extract entire row when a value is found

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that check in different columns for all the dates that are `>= "2022-03-01" and i <= "2024-12-31` then it append it to a list `ext=[]`.

What I would like is to be able to extract the more information about located on the same row.

My code:

```
from pandas import *

data = read_csv("Book1.csv")

# converting column data to list
D_EXT_1 = data['D_EXT_1'].tolist()
D_INT_1 = data['D_INT_1'].tolist()
D_EXT_2 = data['D_EXT_2'].tolist()
D_INT_2 = data['D_INT_2'].tolist()
D_EXT_3 = data['D_EXT_3'].tolist()
D_INT_3 = data['D_INT_3'].tolist()
D_EXT_4 = data['D_EXT_4'].tolist()
D_INT_4 = data['D_INT_4'].tolist()
D_EXT_5 = data['D_EXT_5'].tolist()
D_INT_5 = data['D_INT_5'].toList()
D_EXT_6 = data['D_EXT_6'].toList()
D_INT_6 = data['D_INT_6'].toList()

ext = []

ext = [i for i in D_INT_1 + D_INT_2 + D_INT_3 + D_INT_4 + D_INT_5 + D_INT_6 if i >= "2022-03-01" and i <= "2024-12-31"]

print(*ext, sep="\n")
```

Example of data:

```
NAME,ADRESS,D_INT_1,D_EXT_1,D_INT_2,D_EXT_2
ALEX,h4n1p8,2020-01-01,2024-01-01,2023-02-02,2020-01-01
```

What my code will print with that data:

```
2024-01-01
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**:

```
Alex, 2024-01-01
```

As requested by not_speshal
-> data.head().to_dict()

```
{'EMPL. NO': {0: 5}, "NOM A L'EMPLACEMENT": {0: 'C010 - HOPITAL REGIONAL DE RIMOUSKI/CENTRE SERVEUR OPTILAB'}, 'ADRESSE': {0: '150 AVENUE ROULEAU'}, 'VILLE': {0: 'RIMOUSKI'}, 'PROV': {0: 'QC'}, 'OBJET NO': {0: 67}, "EMPLACEMENT DE L'APPAREIL": {0: 'CHAUFFERIE'}, 'RBQ 2018': {0: nan}, "DESCRIPTION DE L'APPAREIL": {0: 'CHAUDIERE AQUA. A VAPEUR'}, 'MANUFACTURIER': {0: 'MIURA'}, 'DIMENSIONS': {0: nan}, 'MAWP': {0: 170}, 'SVP': {0: 150}, 'DERNIERE INSP. EXT.': {0: '2019-05-29'}, 'FREQ. EXT.': {0: 12}, 'DERNIERE INSP. INT.': {0: '2020-06-03'}, 'FREQ. INT.': {0: 12}, 'D_EXT_1': {0: '2020-05-29'}, 'D_INT_1': {0: '2021-06-03'}, 'D_EXT_2': {0: '2021-05-29'}, 'D_INT_2': {0: '2022-06-03'}, 'D_EXT_3': {0: '2022-05-29'}, 'D_INT_3': {0: '2023-06-03'}, 'D_EXT_4': {0: '2023-05-29'}, 'D_INT_4': {0: '2024-06-03'}, 'D_EXT_5': {0: '2024-05-29'}, 'D_INT_5': {0: '2025-06-03'}, 'D_EXT_6': {0: '2025-05-29'}, 'D_INT_6': {0: '2026-06-03'}}
```

Comment: I'm new to pandas so don't know the exact solution here. Converting your data frame to a list and looping over it seems anti-thetical to the pandas way. Instead, you should use "broadcasting".

Comment: Your present code does check nothing (`>= "2022-03-01" and <= "2024-12-31`)?

Comment: Can you please include the output of `data.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: the data are dates, and I want every dates that are inside ` >= "2022-03-01" and <= "2024-12-31 `. What is your question? @Corralien

Comment: `from [module] import *` is highly anti-pythonic; you'll see most `pandas` users do `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_csv(file)`

Comment: @not_speshal I added the output

Comment: So there's no NAME or ADDRESS column in your data? How do you expect to get these values then?

Comment: wait sorry @not_speshal I will update it, it's a mistake

Comment: OK It's updated, but I only used 1 line of my table. IT's 1800 lines and theres sensitive information, so I only used the first row with all the columns. @not_speshal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```py
import pandas as pd
cols = [prefix + str(i) for prefix in ['D_EXT_','D_INT_'] for i in range(1,7)]

data = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
for col in cols:
  data.loc[:,col] = pd.to_datetime(data.loc[:,col])
```

Then use

```py
ext = data[
    (
      data.loc[:,cols].ge(pd.to_datetime("2022-03-01"))\
      & data.loc[:,cols].le(pd.to_datetime("2024-12-13"))\
    ).any(axis=1)
  ]
```

EDIT: while it's not clear what date you want if multiple are in the required range, to get what (I understand) you're requesting, use

```py
# assuming
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# and
cols = [prefix + str(i) for prefix in ['D_EXT_','D_INT_'] for i in range(1,7)]

ext = data[
    np.concatenate(
      (
        np.setdiff1d(data.columns,cols), 
        np.array(
          (data.loc[:,cols].gt(pd.to_datetime("2022-03-01"))\
            & data.loc[:,cols].lt(pd.to_datetime("2024-12-13"))\
          ).idxmax(axis=1)
        )
      ),
      axis=None
    )]
```

where `cols` is as above

Comment: `df` ? did you meant `data`?

Comment: Fixed; I defaulted to using `df` XD

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working great, but Can I add something? I would like to extract all the lines before  'D_EXT_1' && extract the date found between 2022-03-01 and 2024-12-31. Is it possible? Because in your code it extract the entire row, which is great, but I would like to change that if possible!

Comment: @ChNa IIUC, the last code block will do what you need

Comment: i'm getting [1692 rows x 1715 columns] running your last block of code on my real .csv file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try:

```
columns = ['D_EXT_1', 'D_EXT_2', 'D_EXT_3', 'D_EXT_4', 'D_EXT_5', 'D_EXT_6', 'D_INT_1', 'D_INT_2', 'D_INT_3', 'D_INT_4', 'D_INT_5', 'D_INT_6']
data[columns] = data[columns].apply(pd.to_datetime)
output = data[((data[columns]>="2022-03-01")&(data[columns]<="2024-12-31")).any(axis=1)]
```

This will return all the rows where *any* date in the columns list is between `2022-03-01` and `2024-12-31`

Comment: The only comment I'd make is `df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)` is arguably better replaced by `df[cols] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols])` and by that point our answers are quite similar ;)

Comment: What version of pandas are you using @JoshuaVoskamp? [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) does not accept a DataFrame unless it's a component frame to build a single datetime. I can't recall `to_datetime` ever being able to convert multiple columns without apply but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @HenryEcker you're right; that code does not work verbatim. See my answer; I used a `for` loop to loop over the columns.  TL;DR `.apply(pd.to_datetime)` is (in some cases) the less performant option.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp - HenryEcker beat me to it. I also get a `ValueError` when using `pd.to_datetime` on a DataFrame. It seems you've edited your answer to use `apply` instead now haha :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to get only rows where at least one of the dates is in the range ["2022-03-01", "2024-12-31"], correct?

First, convert all the date columns to datetime, using [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
import pandas as pd

date_cols = ['D_EXT_1', 'D_EXT_2', 'D_EXT_3', 'D_EXT_4', 'D_EXT_5', 'D_EXT_6', 'D_INT_1', 'D_INT_2', 'D_INT_3', 'D_INT_4', 'D_INT_5', 'D_INT_6']
data[date_cols] = data[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Then create a  2D boolean mask of all the dates that are in the desired range

```
is_between_dates = (data[date_cols] > "2022-03-01") & (data[datecols] <= "2024-12-31")
# print(is_between_dates) to clearly understand what it represents
```

Finally, select the rows that contain at least one True value, meaning that there is at least one date in that row that belongs to the date range. This can be achieved using [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with `axis=1` on the 2D boolean mask, `is_between_dates`.

```
# again, print(is_between_dates.any(axis=1)) to see
data = data[is_between_dates.any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt` to reformat your dataframe to be easily searchable:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv').melt(['NAME', 'ADRESS']) \
       .astype({'value': 'datetime64'}) \
       .query("'2022-03-01' <= value & value <= '2024-12-31'")
```

At this point your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
   NAME  ADRESS variable      value
1  ALEX  h4n1p8  D_EXT_1 2024-01-01
2  ALEX  h4n1p8  D_INT_2 2023-02-02
```

Now it's easy to get a `NAME` for a date:

```
>>> df.loc[df['value'] == '2024-01-01', 'NAME']
1    ALEX
Name: NAME, dtype: object

# OR

>>> df.loc[df['value'] == '2024-01-01', 'NAME'].tolist()
['ALEX']
```