# Extract several values from a row when a certain value is found

Tags: python

I have a code that check in different columns for all the dates that are `>= "2022-12-01" and i <= "2024-12-31`.

What I would like is to be able to extract some other informations located on the same row.

these are the the headers of my columns :

```
EMPL. NO
NOM A L'EMPLACEMENT
ADRESSE
VILLE
PROV
OBJET NO
EMPLACEMENT DE L'APPAREIL
DESCRIPTION DE L'APPAREIL
MANUFACTURIER
DIMENSIONS
MAWP
SVP
DERNIERE INSP. EXT.
FREQ. EXT.
DERNIERE INSP. INT.
FREQ. INT.
D_EXT_1
D_INT_1
D_EXT_2
D_INT_2
D_EXT_3
D_INT_3
D_EXT_4
D_INT_4
D_EXT_5
D_INT_5
D_EXT_6
D_INT_6
```

I would like to search for are all the dates that are between `>= "2022-12-01" and i <= "2024-12-31` in any of the columns with the prefix `D_EXT_x` and extract it with all the information on the row that comes before `D_EXT_1`.

This is the code I got from a question I asked earlier:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = [prefix + str(i) for prefix in ['D_INT_'] for i in range(1,7)]

data = pd.read_csv("dates.csv")
for col in cols:
  data.loc[:,col] = pd.to_datetime(data.loc[:,col])


ext = data[
    (
      data.loc[:,cols].ge(pd.to_datetime("2022-12-01"))\
      & data.loc[:,cols].le(pd.to_datetime("2024-12-31"))\
    ).any(axis=1)
  ]

print(ext)
```

The problem is that it's not doing what it's supposed to do. My file has 1692 lines and 29 columns but the output is giving me : [1692 rows x 1715 columns].

here is the original question:
[how to extract entire row when a value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888973/how-to-extract-entire-row-when-a-value-is-found/69889145?noredirect=1#comment123543083_69889145)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get the rows
rows_with_valid_date = df[after_this <= df[date_column_name] <= before_this]

# Get the wanted columns
needed_values = rows_with_valid_date[[wanted_column1, wanted_column2, etc]]
```

You can fill in the correct names where needed.